# How to create random value between two different sets of numbers

Tags: java, random, unicode

I am trying to generate a random character between the following two sets of unicode U+0020 to U+007E and U+00A0 to U+00FF. I have created the code to generate a value between U+00A0 to U+00FF but I also need my generator to include the values from U+00A0 to U+00FF, how is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated, here is what I have so far. (P.S. I am using seed for testing). For example instead of just trying to create a integer between 1-10, I would like to know how to create a random number that could either be between 1-10 or 50-100.

```
  private static char random(){
        long seed = 1776;
        Random number = new Random(seed);
        int randomNumber = number.nextInt(126) + 32;
        char a = (char) randomNumber;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: @GBlodgett Hello and thanks for the reply, however this is quite different as I am trying to create values between to completely different sets. not between one. Example the number could be from 1-10 or 50-100 but in this case it is between two UNICODE sets.

Comment: Why not randomly pick one of the ranges, then generate a random character in that range?

Comment: I don't think you can generate a random value on two different possible ranges. What I would do is merge all of the possible unicode values into one single set then generate a random index in there.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random number to fall in multiple ranges, you first calculate the total number of values in your target dataset, then generate a random number for that total, and assign it to the appropriate set.

Sample code to generate 20 random numbers in ranges 0x20 - 0x7E and 0xA0 - 0xFF, inclusive:

```
int low1 = 0x20, high1 = 0x7E, low2 = 0xA0, high2 = 0xFF;
int count1 = high1 - low1 + 1;
int count2 = high2 - low2 + 1;

long seed = 1776;
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int n = rnd.nextInt(count1 + count2);
    if (n < count1) { // random number is for range 1
        n = n + low1; // offset into range 1
    } else { // random number is for range 2
        n = n - count1 + low2; // offset into range 2
    }
    System.out.printf("%02X ", n);
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
6B 6B A5 DA B3 F7 2B C6 AB F2 3F EE F9 A5 28 31 AD D3 66 B0
```